# Cracking In Audio Using Wave Python Module

Tags: python, audio, wave

I'm using the code below to try to make a simple song, but every time the pitch changes, my speaker has an audible crack. It only happens when I change the duration below 1. The duration is frequencies[index][2]. Is there a way to prevent the cracking?

```
import wave

towrite = ''
x = 0
pause = [1, 1, 0.1]
frequencies = [[90, 1, 1], pause, [90, 1, 0.3], pause, [110, 1, 0.4], pause, [90, 1, 0.4], pause, [78, 1, 0.4], pause, [72, 1, 1], pause, [66, 1, 1]]
for freq in frequencies:
    if(x%100==0):
        print(x)
    x+=1
    samplerate = 88200
    samples = freq[2]*samplerate
    period = samplerate / float(freq[0])
    period2 = samplerate / float(freq[1])# in sample points
    omega = np.pi * 2 / period
    omega2 = np.pi * 2 / period2

    xaxis = np.arange(samples,dtype = np.float)
    ydata = 16384 * (np.sin(xaxis*omega) + np.sin(xaxis*omega2))

    signal = np.resize(ydata, (samples,))

    towrite += ''.join([wave.struct.pack('h',s) for s in signal])

    f = wave.open('frequency.wav', 'wb')
    f.setparams((1,2,44100, 44100*4, 'NONE', 'noncompressed'))
    f.writeframes(towrite)
    f.close()
```

Comment: For starter, `samples` is a `float` for `freq[2]` different than integer. The code as presented here shouldn't work, `signal = np.resize(ydata, (samples,))` would complain about float for non-integer duration (so it's not only below 1, above 1 would be as bad).

Comment: @LukaszTracewski yeah, I fixed that after posting this, but before I fixed it, the code still ran. The problem is not in running it, it's when the the audio file is made, in between each tone, the speaker cracks(it isn't the speaker).